# angular $resource delete won't send body to express.js server

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

hye,

i am building an app with angular.js and node.js (Express.js) on the server side.

for some reason i am having a problem handling a delete request. no body is getting to the server side.

this is my angular.js resource code:

```
$scope.deleteProject = function(projectName){
    var postData = {username: 'name', projectName: projectName};
    Project.deleteProject.delete({}, postData,
        function(res){
            alert('Project Deleted');
        },
        function(err){
            alert(err.data);
    });
}
```

on the server side i have this:

```
var deleteProject = function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.params);
    if (req.body.projectName){
        //do something
        return res.send(200);
    }
    else
        return res.send(400, 'no project name was specified');
}
```

now for some reason there is no body at all!! it is empty.
i have defined the route as app.delete.

if i change the route in node.js to post and in angular.js to save it works fine.

what am i missing here (banging my head).

thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a clean way to send a body with DELETE request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159213/what-is-a-clean-way-to-send-a-body-with-delete-request)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As per [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15159213/pretty-coding-to-send-body-with-delete-request-in-angular-js) and the [`$http` service source code](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), a `DELETE` request using `$http` does not allow for data to be sent in the body of the request.  [The spec for a DELETE request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) is somewhat vague on whether or not a request body should be allowed, but Angular does not support it.

The only methods that allow for request bodies are `POST`, `PUT`, and `PATCH`. So the problem is not anywhere in your code, its in Angular's `$http` service.

My suggestion would be to use the generic `$http(...)` function and pass in the proper method:

```
$http({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: '/some/url',
    data: {...},
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'}
})
```

Comment: why put? it seems very wrong to make a put request for a deletion. maybe post?

Comment: PUT is generally used for a "modification" of the existing record.  POST is typically used for "creation".  It doesn't really matter which one you use, so its really up to you.

Comment: Is there any reason why all the http service codes do not support having a body attached? Currently I'm mainly using the service codes for semantic purposes.

Comment: If it were up to me, I would have allowed a request body for all request types, but the Angular team for some reason decided not to support it for deletes.  Not sure why. I don't know that there is really a reason.

Comment: When you say that `$http` doesn't support body on DELETE you should state that you're referring to `$http.delete()` function. If you used simply `$http(config)` it's totally possible to send message body even with deletes...

Answer (score 37):

Angular by default sends the Content-Type as text/plain for DELETE requests. Just add this to the headers:

```
  var config = {
    method: "DELETE"
    url: yourUrl
    data: yourData
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"}
  };

  $http(config);
```

If you want to add them to every single DELETE request add this to the app.config method in your main controller:

```
 $httpProvider.defaults.headers.delete = { "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8" };
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the $resource object instead of $http you need to add `hasBody` and `headers` as follow:

```
delete:  {
    method: 'DELETE',
    hasBody: true,
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"}
  }
```

Worked for me

Comment: hasBody was added in angular 1.6.4, so if you're using an earlier version this will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this problem. You'll have to use url params to send an id with delete.

in express:

```
app.delete('/api/user/:userId', user.remove);
```

and add to the url in angular:

```
$http({url: 'whatever/api/'+obj.id, method: 'DELETE'}) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json;charset=utf-8';
```

XMLHttpRequest is optional but useful if you are sending ajax.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$httpProvider for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.delete = { "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8" };
```

And then

```
$http.delete(url, { data: data })
```