# Empty (req.body) on delete (angular)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose

I am using mongoose, express.js and angular.js

My Problem is that i am getting an empty req.body.

I would appreciate any help.
Thank you.

```
$http({
        method:'DELETE',
        url:'/api/delete',
        data:$scope.selected._id
    }).success(function (data) {
        alert("worked");
    }).error(function(e){
        alert("not");
    });
});


app.delete('/api/delete', function(req,res, next){

console.log(req.body);
Model.remove({"_id":req.body},function(err){
    if(err){
        res.send(err);
    }else{
        res.json("Worked");
    }

});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular $resource delete won't send body to express.js server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186671/angular-resource-delete-wont-send-body-to-express-js-server)

Answer (score -1):

Are you using body-parser middleware within your express app?  By default the request object will not have a body key.

Here is how you could add it to your app.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')


// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```