# Pass request parameter to delete request in rest

Tags: java, rest, resteasy

I am using resteasy. Here is a code to delete a resource.

```
@DELETE
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/{id:\\d+}")
public Response removeResource(@PathParam("id") int id){
    .........................
    .. code to delete resource and return Response object ..
    .........................
}
```

This code is working fine. But when I try to pass some parameter to delete request. I am getting `UnsupportedMediaException`

```
@DELETE
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/{id:\\d+}")
public Response removeResource(@PathParam("id") int id, Map<String, Object> source){
    .........................
    .. code to delete resource and return Response object ..
    .........................
}
```

I need to send some parameter for some reason. Moreover when I just replace `delete` request with `put` request i.e. replacing `@DELETE` with `@PUT`, the code works fine.

Is there any way to pass parameter to delete request.

And at front end I was using angularjs's $resource to send DELETE request

```
var r = $Resource(/rest/resources/1);    // for debugging purpose I made id 1
r.remove({"key1":"data1", "key2", "data2"});
```

**Edit :**
Stack trace from server

```
11:43:25,767 ERROR [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-7) RESTEASY002010: Failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: RESTEASY003065: Cannot consume content type
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SegmentNode.match(SegmentNode.java:382)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SegmentNode.match(SegmentNode.java:116)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootNode.match(RootNode.java:43)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:48)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:445)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:257)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:194)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
```

Response at front-end

```
Status Code: 415 Unsupported Media Type
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 01 Jun 2016 06:13:25 GMT
Server: WildFly/10
x-powered-by: Undertow/1
```

Comment: Can you show the complete stacktrace

Comment: Also some servers don't support a body with DELETE. Though the `UnsupportedMediaException` sounds like a RESTEasy exception, so the error is happening at the application level. I am not quite sure RESTEasy's rules regarding this. Worst case, just send the data in query parameters

Comment: @peeskillet I added stacktrace of web server and response at front end

Comment: Maybe this is a [client side problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22186671/2587435). What details does the browser developer tools show about the request? Have you checked it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have requested that the Content-Type be "application/json"
AngularJS [defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23919029/4951015) to text/plain.

If you have a new enough version of AngularJS(1.1.3) you can customise the resource object to include the Content-Type you requested.
You should be able to modify your resource definition to include the Content-Type for a delete request

```
var r = $Resource(/rest/resources/1, {},
   remove:{
      method:"DELETE",
      isArray:false,
      headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=UTF-8'} 
   }
);
```

For more info see [Answer One](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15801545/4951015) and [Angular issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/736)